# SSRS - Suppression and column total on duplicates

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report where I need to suppress columns of text when they are dupicate (done) but also total two columns of figures (net debit & credit) leaving the other two columns (ccy & ccy amount) itemised as they are.

When dealing with data like:

```
DESCRIPTION                  DEBIT        CREDIT     CCY    CCY AMOUNT
332300 Creditors              0.00          0.50     EUR         -0.50
339003 Sundry Creditors       0.00      4,423.39     EUR     -4,423.39
339003 Sundry Creditors   4,241.50          0.00     GBP      3,587.50
340101 Ordinary Shares        0.00          1.41     GBP         -1.00
395000 Revenue Reserves       0.00    196,850.46     EUR   -196,850.46
395000 Revenue Reserves       0.00    967,816.68     GBP   -797,995.90
```

I have managed to surpress the description when duplicated but would like to only display the appropriate net debit or credit amount just leaving the ccy and amount itemised, like this:

```
DESCRIPTION                  DEBIT        CREDIT      CCY    CCY AMOUNT
332300 Creditors                            0.50      EUR         -0.50
339003 Sundry Creditors                   181.89      EUR     -4,423.39
                                                      GBP      3,587.50
340101 Ordinary Shares                      1.41      GBP         -1.00
395000 Revenue Reserves             1,164,667.14      EUR  - 196,850.46
                                                      GBP   -797,995.90
```

Any help solving or assisting with this problem would be very much appreciated.

Comment: In your example, is *Sundry Creditors* correct in the final output? Shouldn't it have some GBP component as well?

Comment: Also, what version of SSRS is this?

Comment: Yes, Sundry Creditors is correct, in fig 1 the EUR value is 4,423.39 CR and the GBP equivalent in EUR is 4,241.50 DR giving a net EUR value of 181.89 CR

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a tablix with a group based on the `DESCRIPTION` field (no header row for the group):

[image]

Since you're using SSRS 2008R2 the left most column will be created by default when you create the group, so nothing extra to do there.

We're displaying `CCY` and `CCYAMOUNT` for each row so they are just added as normal fields.

The expressions for `DEBIT` and `CREDIT` are a bit more complicated.

`CREDIT`:

```
=IIf(RowNumber("DESCRIPTION") = 1
        and Sum(Fields!DEBIT.Value, "DESCRIPTION") - Sum(Fields!CREDIT.Value, "DESCRIPTION") > 0
    , Sum(Fields!DEBIT.Value, "DESCRIPTION") - Sum(Fields!CREDIT.Value, "DESCRIPTION")
    , Nothing)
```

And basically just switch the column logic for `DEBIT`:

```
=IIf(RowNumber("DESCRIPTION") = 1
        and Sum(Fields!CREDIT.Value, "DESCRIPTION") - Sum(Fields!DEBIT.Value, "DESCRIPTION") > 0
    , Sum(Fields!CREDIT.Value, "DESCRIPTION") - Sum(Fields!DEBIT.Value, "DESCRIPTION")
    , Nothing)
```

End result looks like your requirements:

[image]

There are two things to note in the above expressions - we only display a result if it is the first row in the Group scope (`RowNumber("DESCRIPTION") = 1`) and also only if the particular column, i.e. `DEBIT` or `CREDIT` is greater than its counterpart in the same group scope.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I also received the following on another forum that worked ok but thanks for your assistance...this would have also worked as I required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution. 
Add one derived column in the dataset query as shown below. I am assuming your dataset is sorted on account description if not you need to sort it.

SUM(-credit+debit) OVER(PARTITION BY AccountDescription) as Net

Use the below expression for Debit column in the SSRS tablix

=Iif(Previous(Fields!AccountDescription.Value)=Fields!AccountDescription.Value,"",Iif(Fields!Net.Value>0,Abs(Fields!Net.Value),""))

Use the below expression for Credit column in the SSRS tablix

=Iif(Previous(Fields!AccountDescription.Value)=Fields!AccountDescription.Value,"",Iif(Fields!Net.Value<0,Abs(Fields!Net.Value),""))